Making command for users to select one of several accessibility colour themes
I have made a number of colour themes using \cs_new_protected:Nn
\bulldrive_operandi:
\bulldrive_operandi_tinted:
\bulldrive_operandi_deuteranopia:
\bulldrive_operandi_tritanopia:

\bulldrive_vivendi:
\bulldrive_vivendi_tinted:
\bulldrive_vivendi_deuteranopia:
\bulldrive_vivendi_tritanopia:

Here is a short declaration
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bulldrive_vivendi_deuteranopia:
  {
    \definecolor {red}         {HTML} {ff5f59}
    \definecolor {red-warmer}  {HTML} {ff6740}
    \definecolor {red-cooler}  {HTML} {ff6f9f}
    \definecolor {red-faint}   {HTML} {ff9070}
    \definecolor {red-intense} {HTML} {ff5f5f}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bulldrive_vivendi_tritanopia:
  {
    \definecolor {red}         {HTML} {ff5f59}
    \definecolor {red-warmer}  {HTML} {ff6740}
    \definecolor {red-cooler}  {HTML} {ff6f9f}
    \definecolor {red-faint}   {HTML} {ff9070}
    \definecolor {red-intense} {HTML} {ff5f5f}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin {document}

\end {document}

I have the code in a file lamp.sty.  My package will use three separate files, one of them being lamp.sty.
How can I get a user to select what colour scheme to use ?

Can you complete your code to provide a minimal example we can compile? Also, there is not enough information here. What are the colour schemes used for and how are they used? Do they all define the same set of colour names? Is this a package option? Class? Local to an environment? Do you want to use them in PGF? Beamer? MetaPost? For hyperlinks?

Also, your command names are not syntactically correct. If \vivendi: is a control sequence, it should have the name of your module e.g. \bulldrive_vivendi: and so should the rest. Similarly, \bulldrive_operandi_tinted: etc. But defining functions may not be the best way of achieving your goal anyway. E.g. a choice key might be better, in which case you might just as well execute the colour definitions directly.

Why not just define the colours according to the scheme the user selects? Unless you need to install specific sets of colours directly (which it doesn't sound as if you do), defining functions to define the colours just adds an unnecessary mediating layer.
Set up a choice key allowing the user to select and, if appropriate, switch colour schemes and provide a command for setting that key. (Or that and other keys if you want to offer other features, too.)
If you use a standard set of colour names, you can use them, if necessary, in the code of commands and environments you want to provide. Moreover, users can easily switch the colours of their documents by changing the value of the key they set in the preamble. It's obviously more complex if users can switch schemes within the document, but the principle is the same. If they incorporate standard colour names into their source, it is easy to switch to a different palette.
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{\jobname}{2024-05-28}{v0.1}{bulldrive ~ colour ~ selector}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719060/
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\keys_define:nn { bulldrive }
{
  colour ~ scheme .choice:,
  colour ~ scheme / vivendi ~ tritanopia .code:n = {
    \definecolor {base-colour}    {HTML} {ff5f59}
    \definecolor {warmer-colour}  {HTML} {ff6740}
    \definecolor {cooler-colour}  {HTML} {ff6f9f}
    \definecolor {faint-colour}   {HTML} {ff9070}
    \definecolor {intense-colour} {HTML} {ff5f5f}    
  },
  colour ~ scheme / vivendi ~ tinted .code:n = {
    \colorlet {base-colour}    {blue!75!cyan}
    \colorlet {warmer-colour}  {base-colour!95!red}
    \colorlet {cooler-colour}  {base-colour!75} 
    \colorlet {faint-colour}   {base-colour!25} 
    \colorlet {intense-colour} {cyan}     
  },  
  colour ~ scheme / monochrome .code:n = {
    \colorlet {base-colour}    {black!75}
    \colorlet {warmer-colour}  {base-colour!50!black}
    \colorlet {cooler-colour}  {base-colour} 
    \colorlet {faint-colour}   {base-colour!25} 
    \colorlet {intense-colour} {black}     
  },  
  colour ~ scheme .default:n = vivendi ~ tritanopia,
  colour ~ scheme .initial:n = monochrome,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \bulldriveset { +m }
{
%   \color_group_begin: % uncomment if colours should be local
  \keys_set:nn { bulldrive } { #1 }
%   \color_group_end:
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\bulldriveset{colour scheme=monochrome}
\begin{document}
\color{base-colour}\kant[1]

\color{intense-colour}\kant[2]

\bulldriveset{colour scheme=vivendi tinted}
\color{intense-colour}\kant[3]

\bulldriveset{colour scheme=vivendi tritanopia}
\color{base-colour}\kant[4]

\color{faint-colour}\kant[5]
\end{document}

EDIT
Here's a method which lets you define each set of colour definitions as a token list which can be selected using the key colour scheme as before. Each token list should be named \l_bulldrive_<name>_tl where <name> is the name of the colour scheme. If the name contains spaces, you need to use the :c variants of \tl_new:N and \tl_set:Nn i.e. \tl_new:c {...} and \tl_set:cn {...} {...}. If the name is just letters, you can use the regular version.
There's some debate, as far as I can tell, about whether a macro which takes zero arguments should be considered a control sequence or a token list. In this case, a token list feels a bit more appropriate, I think, but they come to the same thing anyway under the hood.
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{\jobname}{2024-05-28}{v0.1}{bulldrive ~ colour ~ selector}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719060/
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\tl_new:c { l_bulldrive_vivendi ~ tritanopia_tl }
\tl_new:c { l_bulldrive_vivendi ~ tinted_tl }
\tl_new:N \l_bulldrive_monochrome_tl
\keys_define:nn { bulldrive }
{
  colour ~ scheme .code:n = {
    \tl_use:c { l_bulldrive_#1_tl }
  },
  colour ~ scheme .default:n = vivendi ~ tritanopia,
  colour ~ scheme .initial:n = monochrome,
}
\tl_set:cn { l_bulldrive_vivendi ~ tritanopia_tl }
{
  \definecolor {base-colour}    {HTML} {ff5f59}
  \definecolor {warmer-colour}  {HTML} {ff6740}
  \definecolor {cooler-colour}  {HTML} {ff6f9f}
  \definecolor {faint-colour}   {HTML} {ff9070}
  \definecolor {intense-colour} {HTML} {ff5f5f}  
}
\tl_set:cn { l_bulldrive_vivendi ~ tinted_tl }
{
  \colorlet {base-colour}    {blue!75!cyan}
  \colorlet {warmer-colour}  {base-colour!95!red}
  \colorlet {cooler-colour}  {base-colour!75} 
  \colorlet {faint-colour}   {base-colour!25} 
  \colorlet {intense-colour} {cyan} 
}
\tl_set:Nn \l_bulldrive_monochrome_tl
{
  \colorlet {base-colour}    {black!75}
  \colorlet {warmer-colour}  {base-colour!50!black}
  \colorlet {cooler-colour}  {base-colour} 
  \colorlet {faint-colour}   {base-colour!25} 
  \colorlet {intense-colour} {black} 
}
\NewDocumentCommand \bulldriveset { +m }
{
%   \color_group_begin: % uncomment if colours should be local
  \keys_set:nn { bulldrive } { #1 }
%   \color_group_end:
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\bulldriveset{colour scheme=monochrome}
\begin{document}
\color{base-colour}\kant[1]

\color{intense-colour}\kant[2]

\bulldriveset{colour scheme=vivendi tinted}
\color{intense-colour}\kant[3]

\bulldriveset{colour scheme=vivendi tritanopia}
\color{base-colour}\kant[4]

\color{faint-colour}\kant[5]
\end{document}


One complication is that the actual list of colours for each scheme is fairly long.  It would be more convenient to call a function that does all the colour definitions.  Can I do such a thing with the convenience of keys but calling a function to define the colour values ?

@Bulldrive You can do what you like. You can put any valid code in there. Just substitute the function for the colour definitions. That's all .code:n means. It means the key executes the code which follows. The code can do anything you want.

@Bulldrive If you name your functions properly, you could even make do with a single key definition rather than using .choice:. So you could have \__bulldrive_colours_set_<name-of-set>: and then just have colour ~ scheme .code:n = {\use:c {__bulldrive_colours_set_#1:}}. As long as you are in charge of the names, it makes sense to make things standard so you can just slot things in.

Yes, I am in charge of the names.

@Bulldrive In that case, please see edit.
